# How would I iterate through the DOM Tree using iMacros

Tags: javascript, dom, imacros

**iMacros**

```
VERSION BUILD=12.0.501.2305
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00
TAG SELECTOR=".class-name"
```

How would I traverse the DOM tree using a class name as the selector in iMacros? In Javascript you would be able to do something along the lines of `.class-name(2)` or `.class-name(3)`, this would normally select something in the dom tree. The problem I'm having is iMacros is not traversing through the tree. Everytime I attempt to traverse the DOM tree it'll just stop after selecting the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play the following line in loop mode:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=* ATTR=CLASS:class-name
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, unfortunately. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: For other ideas provide more details. "_That didn't work for me_" is very uninformative.

Comment: I've updated it. Hopefully that helps a little bit more?

Comment: Do you actually play the macro in **loop mode**? If you simply run the line `TAG POS=2 TYPE=* ATTR=CLASS:class-name`, does it select the second necessary element?

Comment: Aw damn it, I became one of THOSE question askers, I play it in loop mode but it stays at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use xpath in this case:

```
TAG XPATH=".//*[@class='class-name'][{{!LOOP}}]"
```

more info here:

http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#Syntax

http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6621#p20540